# using PHP to remove the extension from a file and then downloading it

Tags: php

I recently had a asked a question very similar to this one, however after evaluating that I did not explain it in the best way I have come back once again explaining it in a greater manner.

So, I am creating a system that will gather data from a MySQL database and use a unique id to download a file, however depending on the value of a column within that database called type, this file could be anything from a png file to an xml file. What I am currently doing is trying to download these files WITHOUT any extension.

As an example to maybe make this easier to understand, a file named image.png would be converted to just image and then downloaded.

With this you could rename the file to image.png again on the local machine and view the image.

This may seem very inefficient to most reading this but for my current situation it's all that will work.

How could I remove a files extension and then download it? (in php)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I edited the question to fit the criteria

Comment: Download from where? Do the files exist without an extension? Are you downloading from a site you control or is it entirely remote?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you using the curl extension or some other client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use headers to specify response type.

```
$filepath = '/wherever/the/file/is.png';
$filename = 'new-cool-name';
header('Content-Type: whatever/content-type-is');
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
readfile($filepath);
```

This basically sends a response with specified content-type as an attachment and the body of the attachment contains the file contents. If you never sure what's the content type is, then just use `application/octet-stream`

Comment: The question seems to be about how to use PHP to download files from some source.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me hours of work I would have needed to do!

Comment: @gview I thought the same but I get the feeling OP actually wants their users to download a file that is the response from their PHP script. The question is poorly explained

Comment: You deserve an upvote for intuition  ;)  Of course the answer is to a problem not really described in the question, but that's not your fault.

Comment: @gview I somehow inferred what the question is all about by reading `a file named image.png would be converted to just image and then downloaded`, but I actually wasn't sure if I'm answering what's being asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you set out to push a file for downloading from a serverside script, you do so by utilizing http headers like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition
The filename of the downloadable file is specified in that header

Answer (score -1):

Okay so to remove an extention from a file you could do is

`$withoutExtion = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $youfilename);`

...followed by your file download code